# Mariadb 10.6 no puedo agregar un índice

Tags: mariadb, index

Estoy intentando crear un indice, siempre me funciono pero desde la versino 10.6 no lo hace, estoy utilizando el comando siguiente
[CREATE OR REPLACE INDEX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-index/)
Y me dice que la entrada esta duplicada de la siguiente manera
ERROR:

```
ERROR DE SQL(102):Entrada dupliada '9' para la clave "tipodeopcion"
```

El error se produce que intento agregar un indice con el siguiente comando:

```
create OR REPLACE UNIQUE INDEX tipodeopcion on nueva.opciones (terminalid) USING BTREE;
```

Siendo la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `opciones` (
    `dato` MEDIUMBLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `datobinario` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `diayhora` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `numero` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `opciones` INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `texto` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `tipodeopcion` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_general_ci',
    `tipop` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `terminalid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`opciones`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tipodeopcion2` (`tipodeopcion`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `terminalid` (`terminalid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `opciones` (`opciones`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=148
;
```

Como se ve lo que quiero agregar es un indice que de unique para las columnas tipodeopcion y terminalid, llamado "tipodeopcion", Y da error incluso con heidisql, al hacerlo por interface, porque es el error a alguien le ha pasado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando crear un índice de tipo UNIQUE, osea, que no permitirá que haya más de un registro con el mismo valor para el campo (o campos) que conforman el índice.

Y te da error, porque los registros que ya existen en la tabla incumplen esa restricción, es decir, hay dos o más registros que tienen el mismo valor para el campo (o campos) que conforman el índice.

En tu caso concreto, tienes dos o más registros con el valor 9 para ese índice.

Por tanto, antes de añadir el índice, debes de solucionar ese problema, por ejemplo haciendo una limpieza de registros repetidos según ese criterio.

Por cierto, el índice lo creas con nombre 'tipodeopcion', pero lo defines con el campo 'terminalid'. El nombre es lo de menos, lo que en tu caso no estás permitiendo repetir es el terminalid, pero como tienes otro campo tipodeopcion, lo mismo te estás confundiendo con algo.